# Is it possible to find buckwheat in Germany?

Tags: germany, food-and-drink

Buckwheat isn't as basic food in Poland as potatoes or bread, but nevertheless very popular. I was quite surprised that I can't find it anywhere in Germany (Nuremberg, Bavaria) in shops like Aldi, Lidl or Norma. In Poland it's available in practically every food shop.

Is buckwheat available in food shops in Germany? If so, in which ones?

Comment: Buckwheat is G-Free, so quite popular with people who can't eat gluten. As such, in the UK you can find it in healthfood shops, and in "free-from" areas in supermarkets, have you tried those in Germany?

Comment: I must try if I find one.

Comment: Also, the brands you mentioned are all discounters. Edeka, REWE or Kaufland are more likely to carry it.

Comment: I don't know Norma, but both Lidl and Aldi are usually cheaper because, among other things, they keep a more limited stock (as in, just one brand of orange juice, just enough chicken for the day, and so on). Perhaps you could try a larger chain, such as Kaufland or Real.

Comment: DM usually carries stuff like that (it should be near the granola). Discounters definitely won't carry specialty items unless they are doing a special offer.

Comment: Last edit has changed the sense of the question. It doesn't have to be polish buckwheat. It may be any buckwheat :)

Answer (score 13):

I would look at some organic stores (*Bioladen* or *Reformhaus*), they should definitely have it. The German name is “*Buchweizen*”.

Alternatively you can [order it online](http://biovyana.com/bio-getreide/146-buchweizen-davert-4019339184103.html).

Answer (score 12):

You should try to search for Turkish or Russian grocery stores in your neighborhood, both of them usually sell ingredients for other Eastern-European and Mediterranean food, and (especially Turkish shops) are usually quite common in the whole country. For example while I was in Bochum, NRW I frequented a shop called [SMAK](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.455315,7.256873,3a,15y,241.93h,88.3t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sGEWc1GwFUS-QS5xu9C4wog!2e0). While I cannot say much about Nürnberg, a quick search showed me a [Russian supermarket](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Lida+Russische+Spezialit%C3%A4ten+Lebensmittelgesch%C3%A4ft/@49.460576,11.093459,3a,81.7y,343.88h,75.27t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1swe0seBVTjnRn09QufaVFFA!2e0!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x6111759d26b6886?hl=en) you might want to check.

Answer (score 8):

As others said, best chances to find *Buchweizen* (german for buckwheat) or *Buchweizenmehl* (the flour) are in so-called “bio” (organic) supermarkets (*denn’s*, *Alnatura*, *Bio Company*, *LPG-Biomarkt* in Berlin…), *Reformhaus*, *Vitalia*, the food section of *dm* drugstores, or the organic/bio sections of non-discount markets like *Rewe*, *Kaisers*, and *Edeka* (“Gut & Gerne” organic brand).

Some common brands:

- *[Rapunzel](http://www.rapunzel.de/bio-produkt-buchweizen--403430.html)*
- *[Alnatura](http://www.alnatura.de/Alnatura%20Produkte/Produktsuche/Buchweizen)*
- *[Demeter](http://shop.spielberger-muehle.de/spielberger-buchweizen-demeter-500g)*
- [*Bauck Hof* flour](http://www.bauckhof.de/de/bauckhof-naturkost-rosche/produkte/bauckhof-produkte/mehl/buchweizenmehl-glutenfrei.html)

Turkish markets like *eurogida* should stock them too, in bigger cities like Berlin there are even specialized Polish shops.

There are some online maps for gluten free food which list markets which are likely to stock buckwheat in Germany:

- http://gfmap.com/
- Berlin only: http://glutenfreiberlin.wordpress.com/glutenfrei-map/